# change font using multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like to know how i can change text font using class i have multiple text with different class i would like to be able to edit all the text without adding another drop down i believe that the change needs to be at script please help me

```js
$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.boy').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.boy').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```html
<div id="something" class="boy">hello world</div>
<div id="something1" class="boy1">hello world</div>
<div id="something2" class="boy2">hello world</div>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
 
   

 
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
        <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="AR Berkley">AR Berkley</option>
        <option value="AR Blanca">AR Blanca</option>
        <option value="AR Bonnie">AR Bonnie</option>
        <option value="AR Carter">AR Carter</option>
        
     
    </select>
    
    <select id="size">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>

        
    </select>




 
 </form><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use same `class` for all `div` to follow same font styling.

```js
$("#fs").change(function() {
  //alert($(this).val());
  $('.boy').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
  $('.boy').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```html
<div id="something" class="boy">hello world</div>
<div id="something1" class="boy">hello world</div>
<div id="something2" class="boy">hello world</div>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

  <select id="fs">
    <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
    <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="AR Blanca">AR Blanca</option>
    <option value="AR Bonnie">AR Bonnie</option>
    <option value="AR Carter">AR Carter</option>
  </select>

  <select id="size">
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>

  </select>





</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: what i need is to change individually not all together

Comment: If you want that, you need something(on the page) to select which element to be styled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(“*”).css(“font-size”,”15px”);
```

But to use `*` selector should be avoided.

Comment: Becareful on your *double-quote*. `“ ”`, is `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but , either of this workaround will suit you 
Method 1:
You can add multiple classes in the jquery selector and change the font by css method.`$(".boy,.boy2.boy3").css("font-family", $(this).val());`

Method 2: It will be tiring to add multiple classes each time so either you wrap all your div inside another div like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="something" class="boy">hello world</div>
   <div id="something1" class="boy1">hello world</div>
   <div id="something2" class="boy2">hello world</div>
</div>
```

And you can add jquery selector over it like this :

```
$("#wrapper >div").css("font-family", $(this).val());
```